# wput on Windows ignoring --skip-existing

Tags: windows, ftp, cmd

Hopefully someone familiar with wget & wput on windows knows about this...

> wput -v --remove-source-files --skip-existing --dont-continue %stfile% ftp://%ftpuser%:%ftppass%@%ftpserver%/inbound/%stfile%

basically this should *not* try to ftp the file if it already exists on the ftp site... however the file does not exist-- and it does *not* transfer the file

--remove-source-files is like doing a move, it still does not work if removing it--

it works correctly if the file is there--

Skipping this file due to resume/upload/skip rules.
-- Skipping file: %stfile% 
FINISHED --17:37:30--
Skipped 1 file.

this might be a bug, but who knows...

wput is not as actively developed as wget--

thanks!

Comment: It must be a bug, I didnt have time to file a bug report yet etc., & ended up using winscp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a bug for me, but it works fine on Ubuntu 9.04. Weird.

File a bug report at [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=141519&atid=749613).

Answer (score 0):

A few years late, but might help someone else...

Try running with -v -d to get more information

```
wput file.ext ftp://User:pass@domain/path -v -d
```

You might find that the reason it failed was because you were using an empty file as a test, in which case you would see this

```
==> SIZE bob.txt ... ---->SIZE bob.txt
[550] 'File not found'
failed.
local_fsize: 0
target_fsize: 0
resume_table: 1,0,2
Skipping this file due to resume/upload/skip rules.
-- Skipping file: bob.txt
processing queue:
Connection ended. (14002c0)
Checking whether 332 is writable... 1 (0:No error)
---->QUIT
[221] 'Goodbye'
Closing socket 14002c0
FINISHED --15:17:16--
Skipped 1 file.
```

Which seems to imply it will refuse to copy a 0 size file if there is no file to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, turned out I had to terminate the path with `/`.